# Change Button's enabled color without changing disabled color

Tags: android, android-view, android-button, android-theme, android-styles

I'm using the element *Button* for my xml layout. *Button class* from *android.widget* that extends *TextView*.

This view has a possibility to tag as enable or disable by java code. `.setEnabled(true|false)`.

Button xml code

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/maps_list_save_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/str_save"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

**What I wanna:**

[image] When my button is enable I wanna give him a purple color.

[image] When my button is disable get a grey color.

**What I don't wanna do:**

Create a new element and include the layout, I'm avoiding this because I wanna keep the selected animation, raise, padding, elevation etc. Create everything again is not smart.

**What I already try:**

*Change the Background* = it loose the inside padding, what make the button bigger and I wanna keep the material design "rules"
[image][image]

*Change Theme* = I tried to change the theme, by editor and by code but two things happen: or I change more stuffs that are not the button or I change the Enable and Disable for the same color.

Even looking for the docs I did not found how to use properly this element.

Comment: Did you try using `selector`?

Comment: @MdSufiKhan where and how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need is to change `android:colorAccent` value for specifically that `Button`. That can be achieved with applying a theme to the `Button`.

Inside `styles.xml` introduce following changes:

```
<style name="PurpleTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#8654e2</item>
</style>
```

Then declare following two buttons in the xml file, where first button has enabled state, and second button has disabled state.

```
<Button
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"
    android:theme="@style/PurpleTheme" />

<Button
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="Button 2"
    android:theme="@style/PurpleTheme" />
```

Pay attention, that buttons are applied:

- `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"`
- `android:theme="@style/PurpleThemeOverlay"`

Then you'll get following output:

[image]

Comment: Only using the `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"` already work, thanks! I cannot bounty yet, but I will

Comment: @Canato, that means, that you have applied `colorAccent` to the theme of the activity. If you wanted activity to be themed with a different `accentColor` and the button with another color, then this is the correct way. Also, feel free to **not** award bounty yet, as long as it's possible someone may come up with a better answer. This answer will get awarded automatically, as long as it is an accepted one. Thanks.

Comment: @Canato, slightly changed the answer. No need for `ThemeOverlay`s.

Comment: My IDE is telling me I need api level 21 to use android:colorAccent.  What is the work around for a lower api?

Comment: @tzg, if you use appcompat theme it should be `<item name="colorAccent">#8654e2</item>`

Comment: In my case, i used the same as above, but it worked with `android:colorPrimary` or `colorPrimary`

Answer (score 3):

You can use selector like below to achieve this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_enabled="true">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="Your Color"></solid>
      <corners android:radius="5dp"></corners>
      <padding android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp"
          android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp"></padding>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: And how I put this in button element?

Comment: @Canato Use this android:background ="@drawable/selector.xml"

Comment: I write on the question, if I change the background I lose the inside padding etc. You can see in "What I already did > Change Background" =)

Comment: Just post on the question. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: @Canato I understand your problem.. I have updated my answer please check it with this. This is happening, because button has a default background with intrinsic padding of left and right, since we are changing the background its happening. Hope my answer will help for question

Comment: I tried, but keep killing the padding. The state_enable work, but raise, pressed was killed was well =/